# What is the proper way to use plaid with php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, plaid

I am using

> [travoltron/plaid](https://github.com/travoltron/plaid)

for laravel(5.6).

Plaid package version is "travoltron/plaid": "^2.0" and guzzle version is "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.0".

I have followed the documentation and placed

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID=**********************

PLAID_SECRET=**************************
```

in .env file.

now when i use

```
use Plaid;

public function auth() {
        $authUser = Plaid::addAuthUser('user_good', 'pass_good', null, 'chase');
        return $authUser;
    }
```

it show me an error "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable".
[image]

If my approach regarding using this package is wrong please suggest me better way
or guide me.

Comment: please post the code you are actually using.

Answer (score 3):

So, the Plaid package you're using is from an unofficial (community-maintained) package that hasn't been updated in 3 years.

While we can't really support community packages, I'd at least suggest using a more actively maintained library, like this one by TomorrowIdeas: https://github.com/TomorrowIdeas/plaid-sdk-php

Comment: how you create access token for further access of API's in postman collection we use "/sandbox/public_token/create" then "/item/public_token/exchange" to create access token but in this package i didn't find a way could you please give a hint.

Comment: It looks like the SDK has methods for both of them -- /sandbox/public/token create appears to be here: https://github.com/TomorrowIdeas/plaid-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Resources/Sandbox.php#L15 and and /item/public/token exchange appears to be here: https://github.com/TomorrowIdeas/plaid-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Resources/Items.php#L71

Comment: api "/link/token/create" return me a link, can i create access token without link like we create via "/sandbox/public_token/create"?

Comment: use TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\Plaid;

$plaid = new Plaid(
 $clientId,
 $secretKey,
 $env
);
when i print $plaid it returns empty

Comment: Not sure I understand the first question -- you can use /sandbox/public_token/create like you were doing in Sandbox. No equivalent exists outside Sandbox if that's what you're asking, you have to use Link outside Sandbox. Since the library is third party I can't diagnose why configuring it isn't working for you -- maybe double check that your parameters in the format the library expects and file an issue on their GitHub if it still doesn't work?

Comment: for $plaid->createLinkToken('username', 'es', ['US'],'unique_user_id',["auth"]); it return an error Bad Request btw thanks for collaboration brother.